# Debugging with the projector AS3 Flash projector

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, debugging

I'm working on a Flash game that runs fine when testing through Flash professional, but once it's exported to a projector, it won't run on either PC or Mac.

I've got a PC (Windows 7) and it basically closes the window with a white screen as soon as the projector opens. FWIW, it used to work on a projector until recently when I implemented some new functionality including stage web view, DesktopFacebook API integration etc.

How do I debug this problem with the projector? Has anyone run into issues like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. It actually turned out that Flash was looking for the StageWebView class which isn't available to the standalone projector-- it compiled and ran fine in Flash Pro because I had it set up to test as an Air Desktop app. When I built the projector it didn't throw a compile error at publish time but just refused to load after.

I ended up diagnosing this problem by running the SWF in the debugger projector, which I probably should have just done from the beginning...

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Monster Debugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/downloads)

it should be able to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Vizzy](http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/). It will give you access to all traces and error messages (no code changes required). Or, as AyoubKaanich suggests, you may use a proper debugger.

You must install the projector in [debug version](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) first.